# How can I use StepVerifier instead of block() in tests where I need to store output of reactive code?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When I write tests that verify reactive components I usually use the `StepVerifier` with the following pattern:

```
StepVerifier.create(...)
  .assertNext(...)
  ...
  .verifyComplete();
```

This approach works nice but sometimes it is necessary to grab the produced value and continue the test scenario using it. In this case I have to switch to something like:

```
var producedValue = publisher.block();
assertThat(producedValue)...;
someOtherAction(producedValue);
```

The latter is completely fine and works as expected however I feel that I might miss something and `StepVerifier` API should have an option for doing this as well.

Is there any way to avoid blocking in such scenario and still stick to the `StepVerifier`?

Comment: do you mean something like assertNext?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the `consumeNextWith` operator to grab the value without using `block`?

```
        StepVerifier.create(...)
            .consumeNextWith(producedValue -> {
                someOtherAction(producedValue);
                assertThat(producedValue);
                // if the next action produces a Mono
                //StepVerifier.create(someOtherReactiveAction(producedValue))
                //        .expectNext(result)
                //        .verifyComplete();
            })
            .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: The part of the answer in comment does not work. Using StepVerifier.create().expectNext().verifyComplete() inside consumeNextWith() makes the test run forever

Comment: @aminits I would have to disagree and have verified this with a simple example. Maybe your stream is never completing but I can not really tell without seeing your test. Maybe raise a separate question detailing the issue you are encountering.